# AWS alternative to DNS failover?

Tags: amazon-web-services, high-availability, failover, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I recently started reading about and playing around with AWS. I have particular interest in the different high availability architectures that can be acheived using the platform. Specifically, I am looking for a reliable poor man's solution that can be implemented using the **least amount** of servers.

So far, I am satisfied with solutions for the main HA concerns: load balancing, redundancy, auto recovery, scalability ...

The only sticking point I have is with **failover** solutions.

Using an ELB might seem great, however ELB actually uses DNS balancing under the hood. See [Is AWS's Elastic Load Balancer a single point of failure?](https://serverfault.com/a/612271). Also from a Netflix blog post: [Lessons Netflix Learned from the AWS Outage](http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/04/lessons-netflix-learned-from-aws-outage.html)

> This is because the ELB is a two tier load balancing scheme. The first tier consists of basic DNS based round robin load balancing. This gets a client to an ELB endpoint in the cloud that is in one of the zones that your ELB is configured to use.

Now, I have learned DNS failover is not an ideal solution, as others have pointed out, mainly because of unpredictable DNS caching. See for example: [Why is DNS failover not recommended?](https://serverfault.com/a/60563).

Other than ELBs, it seems to me that most AWS HA architectures rely on DNS failover using route 53.

Finally, the floating IP/Elastic IP (EIP) strategy has popped up in a very small number of articles, such as [Leveraging Multiple IP Addresses for Virtual IP Address Fail-over](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/2127188135977316) and I'm having a hard time figuring out if this is a viable solution for production systems. Also, all examples I came across implemented this using a set of active-passive instances. It seems like a waste to have a passive for every active to achieve this.

In light of this, I would like to ask you what is a faster and more reliable way to perform failover?

More specifically, please discuss how to perform failover **without using DNS** for the following 2 setups:

1. 2 active-active EC2 instances in seperate AZs. Active-active, because this is a budget setup, were we can't afford to have an instance sitting around.
2. 1 ELB with 2 EC2 instances in region A, 1 ELB with 2 EC2 instances in region B. Again, both regions are active and serving traffic. How do you handle the failover from 1 ELB to the other?

Answer (score 2):

You'll understand ELB better by playing with it, if you are the inquisitive type, as I am.

"1" ELB provisioned in 2 availability zones is billed as 1 but deployed as 2.  There are 2 IP addresses assigned, one to each balancer, and 2 A records auto-created, one for each, with very short TTLs.

Each of these 2 balancers will forward traffic to the instance in its same AZ, or you can enable cross-AZ load balancing (and you should, if you only have 1 server instance in each AZ).

These IP addresses do not change often and though it stands to reason that ELBs fail like anything else, I have maybe 30 of them and have never knowingly had a dead one on my hands, presumably because the ELB infrastructure will replace a dead instance and change the DNS without your intervention.

For 2 regions, you have little choice other than using DNS at *some* level.  Latency-based routing from Route 53 can send people to the closest site in normal operations and route all traffic to the other site in the event of an outage of an entire region (as detected by Route 53 health checks), but with this is somewhat more likely to encounter issues with DNS caching when the entire region is unavailable.

Of course, part of the active/passive dilemma in a single region using Elastic IP is easily remedied with HAProxy on both app servers.  It's an http request router and load balancer like ELB, but with a broader set of features.  The code is so tight that you can likely run it on your app servers with negligible CPU consumption.  The instance with the EIP would then balance traffic between its local app server and the peer.  Across regions, HAProxy behind ELB could forward traffic to a mate in a remote region, if the local region is up but for whatever reason the application can't serve requests from the local region.  (I have used such a setup to increase availability of external services, by bouncing the request to a remote AWS region when the direct Internet path from the local region is not working.)

Comment: Should I understand that from your your experience, DNS caching issues have never been an important factor enough to reconsider using ELBs?

Comment: I like the idea of active/passive HAProxy while both apps are active. If perfect failover was the goal, wouldn't this setup be preferred to ELBs?

Comment: re: HAProxy, not necessarily.  An external process has to be responsible for the failover of the EIP itself, and remapping an EIP is quick but not instantaneous.  Note also that the server(s) in passive mode also need an EIP of their own, because every instance in a public subnet needs a public IP if it is making any kind of *outbound* request to the Internet or to most AWS services... so the failover action would actually be to swap EIPs, rather than moving just the one. But the proxy on each instance would communicate with the other app instances using the machines' private IPs, of course.